# get output of perl script from bash script and exit

Tags: perl, bash

From a bash script how can i execute a perl script get the output and exit if value is = 0?
Also in the perl script how do i return the value, do i just return it or do i print it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

perl-script args && exit
```

If you want to continue running, the return value is in $?

Note that there is a distinction between the value returned by the perl script and the output of the script.  To get the output of the script, use the $() operator:

```
#!/bin/bash
output=$(perl-script args)

echo The perl script returned $?
echo The output of the script was $output
```

Comment: actually if the value returned is not 0 i want it to continue running

Comment: I get : command not found when I add && exit in the bash script

Comment: @user391986 'cmd && exit' will exit if cmd returns zero, and will continue running if cmd returns any other value.  Not sure why you are getting command not found.

Answer (score 2):

To get a return code, use the `exit` function. Example:

Perl script:

```
if ($success) {
    $return_value = 0;
} else {
    $return_value = 1;
}
exit($return_value);
```

Bash script:

```
perl scriptname args > outfile && exit
```

That's assuming that you want to exit if the return value of the Perl script is 0 and you want so save the output of the Perl script in `outfile`. If the return value is not zero, it's stored in `$?`, you can save that value to a variable if you please.

Comment: from the perl script do I print "0" or return "0"  also how do I get the perl value inside $return_value

Comment: @user that is the Perl script. You return a value from the script using the `exit` function. You can bind any number you like to `$return_value` like you would normally do in Perl. I added a little more to the perl example to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Your perl script: foo.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# do something and then
exit 1;
```

And inside your bash script foo.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
# do something and then call perl script
perl foo.pl

# check return value using $?
echo "perl script returned $?"
```

Comment: 1 would not mean a successful return value, btw, and `exit 1` needs a semicolon.

Comment: Thanks added missing `;` and correct `1` definitely doesn't mean a successful value, it was just an example.